# Unable to see received message in the AWS CloudWatch log

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch

I am unable to see my message payload in the CloudWatch logs, the data is received as "TOPICNAME:MyTopic/ MESSAGE:PublishIn Status: SUCCESS".

Where instead of message, "PublishIn" displaying.

I want to know how I can see the actual message which I am pushing using MQTT channel, even If I try with AWS Test (Subscribe and Publish), same thing is happening.

I tried metrics option, there I can see message size but not actual message.

I have referred following link to enable CloudWatch logging:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/iot/latest/developerguide/cloud-watch-logs.html

Complete data is coming as:

```
2019-05-17T21:33:16.997+05:30
2019-05-17 16:03:16.997 TRACEID:9dcsce1c-c744-d794-0f88-17b91342b32d PRINCIPALID:dcfc1k7507b7dc6d54e410bf0d887g601f7f0751d520265edf0la34435504p47 [INFO] EVENT:PublishEvent TOPICNAME:MyTopic/ MESSAGE:PublishIn Status: SUCCESS
@ingestionTime
1558109005042
@log
316527181712:AWSIotLogs
@logStream
643d552f-4b45-4d93-a825-875450016595_316527181712_0
@message
2019-05-17 16:03:16.997 TRACEID:9dcsce1c-c744-d794-0f88-17b91342b32d PRINCIPALID:dcfc1k7507b7dc6d54e410bf0d887g601f7f0751d520265edf0la34435504p47 [INFO] EVENT:PublishEvent TOPICNAME:MyTopic/ MESSAGE:PublishIn Status: SUCCESS
@timestamp
1558108996997
```

Comment: are these logs from cloudwatch console ? Baically inorder to see the logs in CloudWatch, you first need to create LogGroups and LogStreams. Each LogGroup can have multiple LogStreams inside it. And then logs gets published to these streams.

Comment: Yes detailed message are from "Logs => Insights" of CloudWatch, the CloudWatch just gives the bellow information: ```2019-05-17 16:03:16.997 TRACEID:9dcsce1c-c744-d794-0f88-17b91342b32d PRINCIPALID:dcfc1k7507b7dc6d54e410bf0d887g601f7f0751d520265edf0la34435504p47 [INFO] EVENT:PublishEvent TOPICNAME:MyTopic/ MESSAGE:PublishIn Status: SUCCESS
2019-05-17 16:03:16.997 TRACEID:9dcsce1c-c744-d794-0f88-17b91342b32d PRINCIPALID:dcfc1k7507b7dc6d54e410bf0d887g601f7f0751d520265edf0la34435504p47 [INFO] EVENT:PublishEvent MESSAGE: IpAddress: 1.21.113.148 SourcePort: 53175```

Comment: Default LogGroups and LogStreams are already created as soon as message is received.